# PowerTop software

Tags: battery, powertop

when i start `sudo powertop --auto-tune` i get message:

```
The file will be loaded after performing the minimum number of measurements (only with battery)//
```

how to fixed this?
ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Powertop needs to record some adjustments to its preferences file first before being able to recomment auto-tune settings. Execute

```
sudo powertop --calibrate
```

while powering your laptop solely by its battery and leave it alone for some time. This can take up to an hour, to be safe. Leave it still running after the measurements tab is displayed. Also make sure auto-suspend is deactivated in the system settings.

After that, quit the program with `Esc` and then you may start it with

```
sudo powertop --auto-tune
```

Comment: this message again(